# Metal frame pool pressure calculation

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question, but I have a real life problem that requires calculation and I do not have the math knowledge to make them myself.

I have an above-the-ground pool, with dimensions of 2x4 meters and water level of 1 meter.

[image]

The only place I have to install it has a slope that will result with 10cm difference in water level. The difference is between the narrow side of the pool. In other words if I will fill the pool with 1 meter water level, on one 2 meter side the water will be 1 meter high and the other side it will be 0.9 meter high.

From my understanding this difference will create more pressure on the wall with the higher water level.

My question is, what water level should I achieve on the higher end so that the pressure on this wall would be as it would have to be if the pool would be on a flat surface with 1 meter water level

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: PSE might work too :) https://physics.stackexchange.com/ Although they are not up much for homework questions sadly.

Comment: I wish it would be homework. But it's a real pool I bought and I'm limited with the place I can put it at my home.

Comment: It would still be considered "homework" as it's not really a research problem. It should not take a lot of time to solve, since this is a static problem.